# React native version mismatch in iOS

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run a react native project and I'm getting this error:

"React Native version mismatch.

Javascript version: 0.59.1
Native version: 0.56.1
"

I've read almost all the google links, the github issues and stackoverflow answers but none of them helped me.

Here's what I tried so far:
  1. Remove node_modules folder and run `npm install` again
  2. Close the terminal window and run 'npm start' again
  3. Restart xCode and build again
  4. Restart the computer and build again
  5. Remove `ios/build` folder and build again
  6. Run `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache"
  7. Remove 'ios/Pods' folder, run 'pod install' and build again

As you see, I tried a lot of solutions and none of them are working.

I'm desperated, I've spent one day trying to make it work and I don't know what else can I do. Help, please!!

[image]

Comment: Can you also try the script mentioned in the error as well?

Comment: sounds like your `package-lock.json` file may be corrupted. remove it and run `npm install`. also, check that the react-native version on `package.json` is indeed the version you intend to run.

Comment: I tried both ways and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I can't believe that I spent two days with this bug, when all I had to do was just to click "Dismiss", the error went away and I can use the app. But anyway, I'm getting this error every time I reload the app and It would be great If I could fix it somehow.